# TabJolt- What 'web edit actions' means?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using TabJolt tool to test my dashboards in tableau. However I find that there is a test plan: 'InteractWebEditVizLoadTest' however I don't understand what this it does in its description: 'simulate web edit actions for 10% of the test time and interactions for 90% of the test time.' So can you please explain me what that 'web edit actions' means and what are the differences with 'interactions'?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Edit is the old name for editing a dashboard on the server.

An interaction is a user browsing the dashboard, applying filters, etc.